# Crossfade 2 divs without click (JS or jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I tried doing several tests. Here's the problem: The former div faded out easily, but the latter div supposed to be fading in without the need of a click. What happened to the latter one is that it blinked.

I want the "preloader" to play for 5s, then crossfade to the "isthis" div.

```js
$(function(e) {
  $('#preloader').fadeOut('1000', function() {
    $('#preloader').replace('#isthis').fadeIn('2000');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="preloader">
  <section>
    <div class="rainbow">
      <div class="bow"></div>
      <div class="bow"></div>
      <div class="bow"></div>
      <div class="bow"></div>
      <div class="bow"></div>
      <div class="bow"></div>
      <div class="bow"></div>
      <div class="bow"></div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
<div id="isthis">
  Here's the other div.
</div>
```

[Here's my JSFiddle, just in case.](https://jsfiddle.net/MaryWilliameTaraneeChristine/98r39jy0/10/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Is this what you looking for.?*

`.replace` will not get you what you want it will not replace the whole content it will only replace the first `occurrence` even if you use `.replaceWith()` it will not help.

It's better to go with `.remove()` and then `fadeIn` the other content.

I have also given `style="display:none;"` to `#isthis` for initial hide.

```js
$(function(e) {
  $('#preloader').fadeOut('1000', function() {
    $(this).remove();
    $('#isthis').fadeIn('2000');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="preloader">
  <section>
    <div class="rainbow">
      <div class="bow">Test</div>
      <div class="bow">Test</div>
      <div class="bow">Test</div>
      <div class="bow">Test</div>
      <div class="bow">Test</div>
      <div class="bow">Test</div>
      <div class="bow">Test</div>
      <div class="bow">Test</div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
<div id="isthis" style="display:none;">
  Here's the other div.
</div>
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much. This will be a big help for a project.

Comment: @TaraneeChristineCourtney I am glad I could be some help, but from now own please do explain the question more clearly.